# Ранее пользователь заблокировал подписку, как перезаписать при его клике

Tags: javascript

При первом посещении сайта пользователи блокируют уведомления/не дают согласие на подписку. Чтобы подписаться на уведомления, необходимо лезть в настройки браузера и из уведомлений удалять сайт, затем вновь обновлять страницу чтобы предложение на подписку уведомлений вновь всплыло.

Допустим, пользователь с первого раза не дал согласие. Возможно ли разместить элемент на странице, при клике на который пользователю вновь всплывет предложение об оформлении подписки?

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, если один раз заблокировали уведомления, то далее в настройках придется разрешать. В Хроме так, по крайней мере.